# Making a "fancy" CV in TeX based on one which is "designed"

Tags: templates, cv

So I just discovered [this](https://www.behance.net/gallery/3835237/Self-Promo). It has a CV which looks like this:
[image]

Can somebody guide me to a template which is similar to this, or otherwise let me know of packages which could help make something similar to this as easy as possible? e.g. How am I supposed to make the text on the left and right side of the lines to get attracted to the middle lines?

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to understand why anyone would use an automatic typesetting system like LaTeX for producing such (over)designed pages. I'd simply use Scribus. Even Inkscape would do.

Comment: I disagree that is overdesigned... it is a few text arrangements + variety of fonts....

Comment: Side note: This question is huge with respect to the amount of work for a helper, with very little award at the end. What you can start with is a `tabular`. I would use a tool different from LaTeX though,

Comment: Without any MWE, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087 this question does come off as a raw "do my dtp for me".  Maybe so much that it might be off topic?

Comment: @Johannes_B, I wasn't around for a while. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @AFeldman, thank you for lecturing me on the ethical side of the story. I asked for guiding and useful libraries; that is something any professional can point out (as Johannes_B did) in a few seconds and will take me several hours to come up with... Therefore the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof of concept with two `tabular`s. Uses `fontspec` so has to be compiled with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Fonts used are Fira Sans (https://github.com/mozilla/Fira) and TeX Gyre Chorus.

(Note that this code wont win any awards for elegancy. On the contrary, it's quite the hack job.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\subhead}[1]{{\large\headfont\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par\medskip}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}
\newfontfamily\fancy{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\newfontfamily\headfont{Fira Sans}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\sffamily

{\fancy\noindent\fontsize{45}{48}\selectfont hey, hi

and Hello!\par}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}[t]{
  >{\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}|}
\subhead{PROFILE}

This person is a strange character that I know nothing about.

{\fancy\fontsize{40}{42}\selectfont That person can do this\par\medskip}

Name and address
\end{tabular}\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|>{\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.6\linewidth}}
\subhead{Education}
This\newline
that

\subhead{Employment}

Been there \newline
Done that
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks better than the original.

Comment: @Johannes_B The `tabular` was your idea though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., Wow Thanks a lot! :)   I didn't expect to to get a final template! But now I can play around with this.... Thank you so so much! How am I supposed to make the left vertical line shorter than the right one?

Comment: @Naji What did you expect? Anyway, I just had an idea about the lines, will likely update in a bit.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I was just being grateful.... it was beyond my expectation... :)